# Asynchronous functions while validating form data in Javascri[t

Tags: javascript, forms, fetch

I have a sign up form and I have a javascript function while validates the form input with a fetch request to a php file. The code is as follows:

```
form.onsubmit = function() {
    let signInData = JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(new FormData(form).entries()));
    let flag = false;
    fetch('php/sign_up.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: signInData,
    })
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(data => {
        if(data != "1") {
            document.getElementById("sign_up_error").innerHTML = data;
            flag = false;
        } else {
            flag = true;
        }
    });
    return flag
};
```

Now the fetch command requires some time to finish and the .onsubmit function returns a value before it completes. Now I know that an asynchronous function can be used to wait for the fetch to finish using async-await, but have a look. Let's visualize the code for the form:

```
if(form.onsubmit()) {
   sendFormData();
}
```

As you can see, they don't use an asynchronous function on their side to get the data, they use a synchronous function. On their side, form.onsubmit() would evaluate to an empty promise. And an empty promise as a boolean is true, so it would always just send the data. And I cannot use callback since the value has to be returned in that function itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I just found the answer myself using e.preventDefault and flags:

```
let flag = false;

form.addEventListener("submit", formSubmit);

async function formSubmit(e) {
    if(flag === true) {
        return true;
    } else {
        e.preventDefault();
        let signInData = JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(new FormData(form).entries()));
        await fetch('php/sign_up.php', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: signInData,
        })
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(data => {
            if(data != "1") {
                document.getElementById("sign_up_error").innerHTML = data;
                flag = false;
            } else {
                flag = true;
                sign_up.submit();
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

`async` function is executed **asynchronously** if it includes `await` expression. The function is asynchronously completed at the `await` expression, returning Promise (not boolean).
So, we cannot execute the callback function synchronously if it includes `fetch` function that needs `await` expression.

Refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function.

I think the alternative is the following.
The callback always cancel the submission, and then,
when your validation process succeed, submit the form.

```
form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
   e.preventDefault(); // cancel submission
   let signInData = JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(new FormData(form).entries()));
   fetch('php/sign_up.php', {
       method: 'POST',
       headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
       },
       body: signInData,
   })
   .then(response => response.text())
   .then(data => {
       if(data != "1") {
          document.getElementById("sign_up_error").innerHTML = data;
       } else {
          form.submit();
       }
   });
});
```

Comment: But then the next time the form is submitted, again the event default is prevented because of the event listener.

Comment: submit event does not fire by  form.submit().  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit

Comment: Form is just used to refer to the element using document.getElemenyById().

Comment: Yes, I know `form` is a variable of type `HTMLFormElement`, which could be get by `document.getElementById()`, etc.  I think the code work well.